# thrift/TDispatch processor.h No such file or directory error

Tags: makefile, thrift

I am trying to run a Makefile, and coming up with this error:

> thrift/TDispatch processor.h No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated

Thrift is installed in `/usr/local/bin/thrift`, I have make sure by writing thrift in terminal.

Comment: A binary and a header file are not the same thing. Do you have that header file installed under `/usr/local` somewhere?

Comment: No I cannot find this header file in /usr/local, although its present in thrift installation directory thrift-0.9.2/lib/cpp/src/thrift

Comment: Then you either need to install it or point the compilation process at the source directory (using `-I` or flags to a `configure` script).